# Java - using ".contains" in the opposite manner

Tags: java, contains

I want to be able to print a string that doesn't contain the words "Java", "Code" or "String", though I am unsure on how to achieve this as I thought this would be achieved by using '!' (NOT). However, this is not the case as the string is still printed despite the inclusion of the words I want to forbid.

Any advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
System.out.println("Type in an input, plez?");
String userInput6 = inputScanner.nextLine();

if (!userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("Java") || !userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("Code") || !userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("String")) {
    System.out.println("I see your does not string contain 'Java', 'Code' or 'String, here is your string:- " + userInput6);
} else {
    System.out.println("Your string contains 'Java, 'Code' or 'String'.");
}
```

Comment: You need AND (&&), not OR (||). You want to check if doesn't contain all of them, not if it doesn't contain at least one of them.

Comment: `!userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("Java")` - `"Java"` contains an uppercase character after you have converted it to lower case (same with other calls).

Comment: Do you understand what does `toLowerCase()` do ? why are you using it?

Comment: `toLowerCase().contains("Code")` is false forever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought this would be achieved by using '!' (NOT)

It is. You just haven't applied it correctly to your situation:

You start with this statement:

```
userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("java") ||
userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("code") ||
userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("string")
```

which checks if the input contains *any* of these, and you wish to negate this statement.

You can either wrap the entire statement in parentheses (`()`) and negate *that*:

```
!(userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("java") ||
userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("code") ||
userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("string"))
```

or apply the [DeMorgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for the negation of disjunctions which states that the negation of `a || b` is `!a && !b`.

So, as [Carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000206/carcigenicate) stated in the comments, you would need

```
!userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("java") &&
!userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("code") &&
!userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("string")
```

instead.

Your statement is simply checking if the string doesn't contain *at least one* of these substrings. This means the check would only fail if the string contained *all* of these strings. With `||`, if any operand is `true`, the entire statement is `true`.

Additionally, [mkobit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/627727/mkobit) makes the point that your strings you are checking for should be entirely lowercase. Otherwise, you are checking if a `.toLowerCase`d string contains an uppercase character - which is *always* `false`.

An easier way to think of it may be to invert your `if` statement:

```
if (userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("Java") ||
    userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("Code") ||
    userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("String")) {
    System.out.println("Your string contains 'Java, 'Code' or 'String'.");
} else {
    System.out.println("I see your does not string contain 'Java', 'Code' or 'String, here is your string:- " + userInput6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Since you're using logical OR, as soon as one your `contains` checks it true, the entire condition is true. You want all the checks to be true, so you need to use logical AND (`&&`) instead
- As @mk points out, you have another problem. Look at:

  ```
  userInput6.toLowerCase().contains("Java")
  ```

  You lower case the string, then check it against a string that contains an uppercase. You just removed all uppercase though, so that check will always fail.

Answer (score -2):

Also, you can use regexp :)

```
boolean notContains(String in) {
    return !Pattern.compile(".*((java)|(code)|(string)).*")
                   .matcher(in.toLowerCase())
                   .matches();
}
```

Or just inline it:

```
System.out.println("Type in an input, plez?");
String userInput6 = inputScanner.nextLine();
if (!Pattern.compile(".*((java)|(code)|(string)).*")
            .matcher(userInput6.toLowerCase())
            .matches()) {
    System.out.println("I see your does not string contain 'Java', 'Code' or 'String, here is your string:- " + userInput6);
} else {
    System.out.println("Your string contains 'Java, 'Code' or 'String'.");
}
```

Comment: "[Now](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) [you](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski#Attributed) [have](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/05/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems/) [two](https://xkcd.com/1171/) [problems](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10083420)"

Comment: @StephenP, Yeah, but only one left. the original problem is solved :)